# Detect language and translate string to English in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I would like to detect the language of strings within a pandas series and translate the strings from their detected languages to English.

```
df['Comments'][:7]
0                                                        @bertelsen1986
1                               20 or 30 mm rise on the Renthal Fatbar?
2                                            Luckily I have one to 
3                                   @hatsofftojj isn’t this a dope bike
4                      My bike came with a old GX eagle I have big scam
5                                                                   NaN
6   Also ist ein Spulenschock jetzt ein Daumen hoch auf einem Spektral?
Name: Comments, dtype: object
```

Below is the code that is supposed to detect the language of the strings.
For only 22,000 rows, the code has run for almost an entire day (still running).

```
from langdetect import detect
lang = []    
for row in df.Comments:
    lang = detect(r)
    df['Comments'] = str(df['Comments'])
    df['Language'] = df['Comments'].apply(detect)
```

Comment: Yes, `langdetect` is not the best. Use [`pycld2`](https://pypi.org/project/pycld2/).

Comment: `for i in df['Comments']:df['Language']=cld2.detect(i)` returns an error..